# Line Integral Parameterization

Tags: work, integration

In math, I was taught to parameterize a scalar/vector [line integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral). In physics, I remember doing problems where I didn't parameterize the problem and it still came out correct.

So, by parameterization, you'll always get the right answer. When can you do the line integral without parameterization (i.e., keep everything in terms of Cartesian coordinates and not replacing them with the parameter $t$)?

Wait, in general, a curve can be some squiggly thing where both $x$ and $y$ change simultaneously. So if the path is just a line along the $x$-axis or the path is just a line along the $y$-axis, parameterization is not needed? What about lines in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral of a scalar function / vector field along a curve is *defined* with reference to a parametrization, e.g for a scalar
$$ \int_C f \mathrm{d}s := \int_a^bf(r(t))\lvert r'(t)\rvert \mathrm{d}t$$
where $ r: (a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ is a parametrization of the curve $C$. It is then shown, that the integral is invariant under reparametrization. So the definition does indeed make sense. That is the way you evaluate a line integral. Especially, you have to be careful not to miss the 'velocity' factor $r'(t)$ !

You are right though, that in special cases the parametrization may be trivial. The curve may run along one cartesian axis, for example $r(t):=r(x)=\mathrm{id}(x)=x$. Then $r'(x)=1$ and indeed
$$ \int_{x-axis} f \mathrm{d}s = \int_a^bf(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

In general you do have to pay attention to correctly parametrize the curve. Even in physics.