# Sign on differential in line integral

Tags: electromagnetism, conventions, integration

On p. 36 in Griffiths' *Intro to Electrodynamics* 4th ed., he discusses the line integral along the top side of a positively-oriented rectangle. Specifically, he notes the common error of thinking that the differential $d \vec l = -dx\ \hat x$ along the top, where there should not be a negative sign if the bounds are from the top-right point to the top-left point.

I understand that including the negative in the differential is essentially a double-negative and will not give the correct answer, however I am having a hard time following the mathematical/physical reasoning.

For example, suppose we run a current through the rectangle and put it in a uniform magnetic field. To calculate the force on the rectangle, we need the negative to be in the differential, to represent the fact the current follows the positive orientation of the rectangle, and flows left on the top. If we write the differential as being positive, then the cross product will point in the opposite direction. Clearly, we should integrate from the left to the right to not produce a double negative here, yet this seems very unintuitive. Can anyone provide some insight/intuition for performing line integrals to help me understand the correct mathematical formalism?

Comment: The formalism is that of parameterisation of the line.  I think http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/105604/105142 might have an answer for you if you haven't read that already.